# Android: SQLiteDatabase.insert not inserting

Tags: android, android-sqlite

**Summary**

SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow() executes, does not throw an exception, and returns a positive integer; however, the record is not written to the database.

**Details**

I am implementing the repository pattern, and have a generic base repository.

```
public class BaseRepository<T> implements Repository<T> {

    private enum Operation {
        Add, Update, Delete
    }

    private final SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private final String tableName;
    private final Mapper<T, ContentValues> toContentValues;
    private final Mapper<Cursor, T> toTypeMapper;

    public BaseRepository(Context context, String tableName, Mapper<T, ContentValues> toContentValues,
                      Mapper<Cursor, T> toTypeMapper) {
        this.openHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.toContentValues = toContentValues;
        this.toTypeMapper = toTypeMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T item) {
        transaction(Operation.Add, item, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T item, String filter) {
        transaction(Operation.Update, item, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String filter) {
        transaction(Operation.Delete, null, filter);
    }

    private void transaction(Operation operation, T item, String filter) {
        final SQLiteDatabase database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.beginTransaction();

        try {
            switch (operation) {
                case Add:
                    try { // For debugging, to catch any possible exception
                        ContentValues values = toContentValues.map(item);
                        long result = database.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, values);
                        String temp = ""; // For debugging
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String message = e.getMessage(); // For debugging
                    }
                    break;
                case Update:
                    database.update(tableName, toContentValues.map(item), filter, null);
                    break;
                case Delete:
                    database.delete(tableName, filter, null);
                    break;
            }
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction();
            database.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It gets into the `transaction()` method, and runs the `database.insert()` method. I have set breakpoints and have examined the table name and the values. The table name is correct and the values is correct. The method runs and returns a positive integer, indicating that the insert was successful. However, when I examine the database, the record is not inserted.

I have methods to get data and they are working correctly. If I manually add a row, the `get` method works successfully.

Any thoughts on what is going on here? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I forgot to run `database.setTransactionSuccessful()`:

```
private void transaction(Operation operation, T item, String filter) {
    final SQLiteDatabase database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.beginTransaction();

    try {
        switch (operation) {
            case Add:
                try { // For debugging, to catch any possible exception
                    ContentValues values = toContentValues.map(item);
                    long result = database.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, values);
                    String temp = ""; // For debugging
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String message = e.getMessage(); // For debugging
                }
                break;
            case Update:
                database.update(tableName, toContentValues.map(item), filter, null);
                break;
            case Delete:
                database.delete(tableName, filter, null);
                break;
        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful(); // Added this.
    } finally {
        database.endTransaction();
        database.close();
    }
}
```